# How to debug "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ']'" in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to create a form that list the cars in a cars table and if clicked, sends into another form which is based on a DB query that returns the data of the chosen car (identified by `$modelesc`). This form sends the data to a "orders" table.

I'm now getting the following error in orders.blade.php:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ']'

I don't understand why I'm getting '<'; I don't see this in the code!

This is my code so far:

**CarController**

```
function catalog() {
    $cars = DB::table('cars')->get();
    return view('catalog', compact('cars'));
}

function orders($modelesc=null) {
    $cars = DB::table('cars')->where('Model', '=', '$modelesc');
    return view('orders', compact('cars'));
}
```

**Catalog.blade.php**

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
    {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'CarController@orders', 'method' => 'GET')) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('$modelesc', $car->Model) !!}
    {!! Form::submit($car->Model) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}                                       
@endforeach
```

**Orders.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'index', 'method' => 'POST')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('Model', $car->Model) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden(users_id, Auth::user()->id) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden(Fabrication_date, date(Y-m-d)) !!}
    {!! Form::select('Colour', [
        @foreach($colours as $colour)
            '$colour->Colour' => '$colour->Colour'
        @endforeach
    ]) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden(Order_status_id, '1' !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the structure of the orders table. The *_id fields come from other tables, and I want to fill some values of the forms with the relevant entry (id, users_id, Model, Fabrication_date, Colour_id, Order_status_id).

Comment: You have form elements that have variable declarations that act as constants but are certainly not, like `{!! Form::hidden(users_id, Auth::user()->id) !!}`, isn't that supposed to be `$users_id`?

Comment: I don't have much experience with the `Form` facade, but I suspect the issue is in the nested `@foreach` statement in the select? Behind the scenes, the `@foreach` statement inserts this with `<?php foreach...` so that could be where the hidden `<` is coming from.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Im using laravel 5.4

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to wrap the Form names within quotes, the Order Status ID was also missing a closing bracket:

```
{!! Form::hidden('users_id', Auth::user()->id) !!}

{!! Form::hidden('Fabrication_date', date('Y-m-d')) !!}

{!! Form::hidden('Order_status_id', '1') !!}
```

Next, if $colours is a collection you can do the following in Laravel 5.4 (I'm unsure which version you're using)

```
{!! Form::select('Colour', $colours->pluck('Colour')) !!}
```

If you're on Laravel 5.1 or prior, you'll do the following:

```
{!! Form::select('Colour', $colours->lists('Colour')) !!}
```

This is because the `lists` method was removed in 5.2.

@pseudoanime is also correct with his answer, the database call needs the `get` method adding

Comment: im using laravel 5.4 . $colours is a value that comes from the "colours" table, which connects to the "orders" table. It now shows this error: " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' "

Answer (score 0):

try changing $cars = DB::table('cars')->where('Model', '=', '$modelesc');

```
$cars = DB::table('cars')->where('Model', '=', $modelesc)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your orders method in your CarController doesn't set `$cars` to what you'd think; without calling `get()`, it'll be an instance of Builder instead of an array! Furthermore, you're only fetching cars where the model equals the string "$modelesc" instead of the value of `$modelesc`.

Furthermore, in your `orders.blade.php` file, you seem to reference a `$colours` variable, but that doesn't get passed down in your CarController.

Change your `orders` method to the one below:

```
public function orders($modelesc = null)
{
    $cars = DB::table('cars')
        ->where('Model', $modelesc)
        ->get();

    $colours = DB::table('colours')->get()->pluck('Colour');

    return view('orders', compact('cars', 'colours'));
}
```

There is also an issue with your `Form::select` call in your `orders.blade.php` file; the Blade template directives (`@foreach`, `@endforeach`) are only for the "HTML" portion of the Blade file. Since we called `pluck()` on the Collection of colours in the CarController, we can simply pass in `$colours` for that method.

```
{{-- Incorrect --}}
{!! Form::select('Colour', [
    @foreach($colours as $colour)
        '$colour->Colour' => '$colour->Colour'
    @endforeach
]) !!}

{{-- Correct --}}
{!! Form::select('Colour', $colours) !!}
```

You also appear to be using constants in your Form builders (instead of strings with quotes); these should be strings only.

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'index', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('Model', $car->Model) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('users_id', Auth::user()->id) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('Fabrication_date', date('Y-m-d')) !!}
    {!! Form::select('Colour', $colours) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('Order_status_id', '1') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: I have altered the code. Now i get the message: Parse error: " syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')  " on orders.blade.php

Comment: @Adato We had been missing a closing parentheses in `{!! Form::hidden('Order_status_id', '1') !!}`; make that change and try again. If that didn't do the trick, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42493944/edit) your question to include your changes.

Comment: yes, that parentheses was missing. Now orders is working, but not as intended. It isnt receiving any data from catalog. $cars->count()  is 0

Comment: Well, since im not getting it right and the problem is different and the thread is already old, i will open a new thread.